# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes randomly

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

Please help me with my Ubuntu 16.04. I installed it alongside Windows 2 weeks ago. It freezes randomly since the beginning, which renders it very unstable. I looked up a few similar cases already but nothing seems to work.

When it freezes, it freezes heavy. I cannot use my keyboard nor my mouse. It also doesn't respond to Alt + SYSQR + REISUB (this key combination does work normally when not frozen). I noticed that it 'likes' to freeze when watching movies.

Thought it's a graphics issue, so I tried to updated Kernel 4.5.1 as suggested below. Didn't help though.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/766931/how-to-change-graphics-driver-in-16-04-from-i915-to-open-source-driver/772032#772032

Any help greatly appreciated! Please tell me what other information I need to share here.

System details:

Kernel: 4.5.1-040501-generic

Release:

> No LSB modules are available.
>       Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>       Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
>       Release:    16.04
>       Codename:   xenial

`lshw -c video`:

> description: VGA compatible controller
>   product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
>   vendor: Intel Corporation
>   physical id: 2
>   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>   version: 0e
>   width: 32 bits
>   clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>   resources: irq:89 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff   ioport:1050(size=8)

Comment: Check the answer here I hope that will help you:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/778045/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-often

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ivan, I just updated grub configuration file and I'll see if that helps

Comment: That seems to have fixed my issue. I haven't had any freezes since then. Thanks a lot Ivan!